# Vagrant work flow

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-gatling-rsync

I read about vagrant today, I have observed few points in it.

1. Vagrant creates a identical development environment for everyone in the team.
2. A modern, complex application probably uses a number of external dependencies, like various database servers, message queue etc. Installing these on every developer's machine individually for a local development environment can be quite a difficult. Using a virtual machine image, we can distribute a per-configured environment easily.
3. Have a 5 minute setup for any new developer who joins our team to get up and running. This should be as easy as running a single command: "vagrant up". No installation, no troubleshooting. It should “just work” ™

I have some queries on above statements,

1. How can we setup an environment for new member who joins our team?
2. In case new developer makes some changes in his virtual setup, how will it be reflected or deployed to your virtual setup?
3. Will you have to do the setup again? Or will it work as similar to SVN, namely, if one developer will change it will automatically affect the other machine also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vagrant is a good tool for manage teamwork and create a good startup flow..

1. You can create a git repository with your Vagrantfile and your provisioning script.. a new developer clone your repo and start it with "vagrant up" command.. And he is ready for work with complete env.
2. My configuration of Vagrant is a git repository.. I use it with normale VCS.
3. VCS :) git commit, pull, push ecc how a normal project..

Comment: VCS mean "Version control with Subversion"? If I use SVN will that work right?

Comment: How can we create vagrant file and provisioning script? suggest me any good tutorial or blogs?

Comment: SVN or git is your choose I use git..For example this is my first example of vagrant chef provisionin https://github.com/gianarb/vagrant-base

Comment: Thank you for sharing info @GianArb. I need to know one thing, I need to set do set up on my system, I have vagrant file and package.box and .vagrat folder on my local machine. How to I need to do the same project set up. I have installed the vagrant, vagrant box and git

Comment: I have added the .box to my vagrant box. while running the command "vagrant up" it is throwing error. like host path of the shared path is missing. How to resolve it? the .box is developed in ubuntu and I am working on windows 7? Will vagrant support cross platform or not? Please help me

Comment: Vagrant is cross platform.. sorry but can you follow a simple Getting Start http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/